# Using isin() to determine what should be printed

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Right now I have two dataframes (`data1` and `data2`)

I would like to print a column of string values in the dataframe called data1, based on whether the ID exists in both data2 and data1.

What I am doing now gives me a boolean list (`True` or `False` if the ID exists in the both dataframes but not the column of strings).

```
print(data2['id'].isin(data1.id).to_string())
```

yields

```
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Here is a sample of data1

'user_id', 'id', 'rating', 'unix_timestamp'

```
196 242 3   881250949
186 302 3   891717742
22  377 1   878887116
```

And data2 contains something like this

'id', 'title', 'release_date', 
            'video_release_date', 'imdb_url'

```
37|Nadja (1994)|01-Jan-1994||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Nadja%20(1994)|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
38|Net, The (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Net,%20The%20(1995)|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|1|0|0
39|Strange Days (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Strange%20Days%20(1995)|0|1|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0
```

Comment: Can you show some data in data1 and data2 to us? What exactly you want to print?

Comment: Are id column in both DataFrames unique? Or is unique in first DataFrame or in second? Or nobody know it?

Comment: I would like to print the 2nd column of data2 based on whether the ID exists in whatever dataframe/dataset I'm working with. (Column 1 of data2 is the ID, and Column 2 of data1 is also the ID)

Comment: @jezrael They are not unique ID's

Comment: OK, so check edited answer bellow - I add 3 possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all values of `id`s are unique:

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with `inner` join. For `data2` select only `id` column, `on` parameter should be omit, because joining on all columns - here only `id`:

```
df = pd.merge(data1, data2[['id']])
```

Sample:

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':list('abcdef'),
                      'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                      'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3]})

print (data1)
   B  C id
0  4  7  a
1  5  8  b
2  4  9  c
3  5  4  d
4  5  2  e
5  4  3  f

data2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':list('frcdeg'),
                      'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                      'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],})

print (data2)
   D  E id
0  1  5  f
1  3  3  r
2  5  6  c
3  7  9  d
4  1  2  e
5  0  4  g

df = pd.merge(data1, data2[['id']])
print (df)
   B  C id
0  4  9  c
1  5  4  d
2  5  2  e
3  4  3  f
```

If `id` are duplicated in one or another `Dataframe` use another answer, also added similar solutions:

```
df = data1[data1['id'].isin(set(data1['id']) & set(data2['id']))]
```

---

```
ids = set(data1['id']) & set(data2['id'])
df = data2.query('id in @ids')
```

---

```
df = data1[np.in1d(data1['id'], np.intersect1d(data1['id'], data2['id']))]
```

Sample:

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':list('abcdef'),
                      'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                      'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3]})

print (data1)
   B  C id
0  4  7  a
1  5  8  b
2  4  9  c
3  5  4  d
4  5  2  e
5  4  3  f

data2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':list('fecdef'),
                      'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                      'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],})

print (data2)
   D  E id
0  1  5  f
1  3  3  e
2  5  6  c
3  7  9  d
4  1  2  e
5  0  4  f

df = data1[data1['id'].isin(set(data1['id']) & set(data2['id']))]
print (df)
   B  C id
2  4  9  c
3  5  4  d
4  5  2  e
5  4  3  f
```

EDIT:

You can use:

```
df = data2.loc[data1['id'].isin(set(data1['id']) & set(data2['id'])), ['title']]

ids = set(data1['id']) & set(data2['id'])
df = data2.query('id in @ids')[['title']]

df = data2.loc[np.in1d(data1['id'], np.intersect1d(data1['id'], data2['id'])), ['title']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the *set intersection* of the two columns -

```
ids = set(data1['id']).intersection(data2['id'])
```

Or,

```
ids = np.intersect1d(data1['id'], data2['id'])
```

Next, query/filter out relevant rows.

```
data1.loc[data1['id'].isin(ids), 'id']
```

Comment: So the querying/filtering relevant rows could include strings that are in data1?

Comment: @JonathanHermans sorry, didn't understand your question. It will always include strings in data1, thanks to set.intersection.